# Nulling a item by condition while instantiating

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I have this class

```
public class Item
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public Item(string value)
    {
        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
        {
            Prop1 = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            this = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But `this = null;` doesn't compile. Is it possible to make this behaviour?

```
Item foo = new Item("x"); //foo == null because "x" can't be parsed into int
```

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300904/can-we-interrupt-creating-an-object-in-constructor to find another way

Comment: A constructor returning `null` would be needlessly confusing. Throw an exception instead, or provide a static `TryCreate`. If you want to make something that's "int-like", you can include a [conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators), which could return `null`.

Comment: Remember, `this` is not a variable/property, but simply a shorthand for the reference to the object on which an instance method (including constructor) is being executed. Hence you cannot assign null or anything else to `this`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create static method to create Item:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public Item(int value)
    {
        Prop1 = value;
    }

    public static Item Create(string value)
    {
        int i;
        return int.TryParse(value, out i) ? new Item(i) : null;
    }
}
```

You can than call

```
Item foo = Item.Create("x");
```

If you do not want users to create Items with int parameter, than make constructor private. This way Item.Create(string value) will be the only way user will be able to create Item's instance.

Comment: If you're going to do that, it's probably best to make the constructor `private`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `this` refer to the class instance where the property is declared, you can't make it null from itself.
If you really require that Prop have a value, create a constructor with parameter, check if the value parse to int (why it can't be an int already) and throw an exception if it doesn't

```
public class Item
{
   public Item(string x){
    if (!int.TryParse(value, out temp))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Give me an int to parse");
        }
        else
        {
            Prop1 = temp;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot set an instance to null from within that instance.

A better option might be to have another property (or method) indicating the validity of your class instance

```
public class Item
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid{ get; set; }
    public Item(string value)
    {
        int temp;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
        {
            Prop1 = temp;
            IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But `this = null;` doesn't compile. Is it possibe to make this behaviour?

No you can't do that from inside the class. However you can set any property from there. For e.g. you can do

```
public int? Prop1 { get; set; }
```

and do

```
Prop1 = null;
```